# Запобігти тавтології: широко поширений

Tags: словосполучення

Як найкраще замінити вираз "широко поширений", щоб не було повторення кореня?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Замінити перше слово:

   > [вельми](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7342&page=272) поширений

   Або інший [синонім](//uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8).
2. Замінити друге слово за контекстом:

   - широко [розповсюджений](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozpovsjudzhuvaty)
   - [широковідомий](http://sum.in.ua/s/shyrokovidomyj);
   - [широковживаний](http://sum.in.ua/s/shyroko);
   - [широкодоступний](http://sum.in.ua/s/shyrokodostupnyj).
3. Замінити обидва слова за контекстом:

   - [загальновживаний](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaghaljnovzhyvanyj);
   - [загальновизнаний](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaghaljnovyznanyj);
   - [загальновідомий](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaghaljnovidomyj);
   - [загальновстановлений](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaghaljnovstanovlenyj);
   - [загальнодоступний](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaghaljnodostupnyj);
   - [загальноприйнятий](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaghaljnopryjnjatyj).